# QT ScrollBars doesn't appear with scrollAreaWidgetContents

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qscrollarea

I am trying to learn QT with visual studio. My development environment is VS2015 with QT designer. I am trying to do the following tutorial.

http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QMainWindow_QAction_ImageViewer_B.php

essentially the tutorial displays an image with Qlabel and QScrollArea. If I create the widgets with code (using visual studio) the program seems to work.

```
imageLabel = new QLabel;
imageLabel->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
imageLabel->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
imageLabel->setScaledContents(true);

scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
scrollArea->setWidget(imageLabel);
setCentralWidget(scrollArea);
```

However, then I tried to do the same with QT Designer. When I dragged a ScrollArea from QT Designer, I notices that it also created a QWidget called "scrollAreaWidgetContents". Then when I created the QLabel, Label was created under "scrollAreaWidgetContents" widget. I then tried to display the image using the following code.

```
ui->label->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
ui->label->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
ui->label->setScaledContents(true);

ui->scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
ui->scrollArea->setWidget(ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents);
ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
//ui->scrollArea->setWidget(ui->label);
setCentralWidget(ui->scrollArea);
```

The problem with this is that the scroll Bars never appears. See the attached [image]

Then I uncommented "ui->scrollArea->setWidget(ui->label);" line and then the program compiles but crashes. So, how do I make the scrollBars appear with QT Designer? What am I doing wrong.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Try adding a layout to scrollAreaWidgetContents, and in that layout add the label.

Comment: I tried adding a "form layout" and a "vertical layout". In both I didn't see the scroll bars. When I uncomment "ui->scrollArea->setWidget(ui->label);" it still crashes

Comment: It seems strange to me, share your project to review it